# primefaces p:commandLink in p:datatable doesn't work

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, datatable

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [JSF ajax commandbutton not updating primefaces picklist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8904202/jsf-ajax-commandbutton-not-updating-primefaces-picklist)

I'm using primefaces p:dataTable with celleditor and p:commandLink. p:commandLink doesn't invoke actionListener method. But if I use normal jsf h:commandButton it invokes.
Here is my jsf code:

```
<h:form id="form">
    <p:dataTable var="parent" value="#{adminView.parentlist}" id="parentlist" paginator="true" rows="10" paginatorAlwaysVisible="false" editable="true" styleClass="dtable" style="table-layout: fixed; width: 500px">
            <p:column headerText="Nameр" style ="width: 40%">
                                <p:cellEditor>
                                    <f:facet name="output">
                                        <h:outputText value="#{parent.orgname}"/>
                                    </f:facet>
                                    <f:facet name="input">
                                        <p:inputText value="#{parent.orgname}" style="width: 100%"/>
                                    </f:facet>
                                </p:cellEditor>
                            </p:column>

                            <p:column headerText="Edit" style="width: 10%">
                                <p:rowEditor/>                   
                            </p:column> 
                            <p:column headerText="Delete" style="width: 10%">
                                <p:commandLink onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?')" value="del" actionListener="#{adminView.userOrgRemoveSelected}" styleClass="ui-icon ui-icon-trash" immediate="true">
                                    <f:param name="id" value="#{parent.uorgId}"/>
                                    <f:ajax execute =":form:userlist" render="parentlist :form:selectparent :form:selectparent1 :form:userlist"/>
                                </p:commandLink>
             </p:column>
    </p:dataTable>
</h:form>
```

Here is my bean code:

```
public void userOrgRemoveSelected(ActionEvent action){
    FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    Map<String, String> params = fc.getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap();
    int id= Integer.parseInt(params.get("id"));
    try {
        UserOrganization uorg = userService.getUserOrgById(id);
        userService.removeUserOrganization(uorg);

    } catch (UserException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage("Not possible to delete user"));
    }finally{
        this.parentlist = getUserOrganizationParents();
        this.branchlist = getUserOrganizationBranches();
        this.userlist = getUser1s();
    }    
}
```

Comment: where is the form tag? can you add it?

Comment: answer is here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8904202/jsf-ajax-commandbutton-not-updating-primefaces-picklist